# How to SUM multiple columns from the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following query below.  How do I get the SUM of 'Column 1' and 'Column 2'? X and Y are only sample data to make the question more understandable.

```
SELECT 
'Column 1' = 
    case
        when x = 0 then 2
        when x = 1 then 4
        else 6
    end
,'Column 2' = 
    case
        when y = 0 then 3
        when y = 1 then 6
        else 9
    end
FROM table1
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide more sample data and expected result? =

Comment: @wewesthemenace how is this unclear?  I just said "how to get the sum of column1 and column2'.  Please remove your downvote

Comment: Are you sure it's me who downvoted your question? Without clear sample data and expected result, we can only guess what your requirements are. You already got 4 answers, if none of them is correct, then maybe it's because they didn't understand your question well. Please read [How to ask a question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do some think like this using derive table

```
select sum(p.Column 1) as COL1,sum(p.Column 1) as COL2 from 
(
SELECT 
'Column 1' = 
    case
        when x = 0 then 2
        when x = 1 then 4
        else 6
    end
,'Column 2' = 
    case
        when y = 0 then 3
        when y = 1 then 6
        else 9
    end
FROM table1) as p
```

or using CTE

```
;with cte
as
(
SELECT 
    'Column 1' = 
        case
            when x = 0 then 2
            when x = 1 then 4
            else 6
        end
    ,'Column 2' = 
        case
            when y = 0 then 3
            when y = 1 then 6
            else 9
        end
    FROM table1)
select sum(column1) as COL1,sum(column2) as COL2 from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
sum(
    case
        when x = 0 then 2
        when x = 1 then 4
        else 6
    end) 'Column 1'
,sum( 
    case
        when y = 0 then 3
        when y = 1 then 6
        else 9
    end) 'Column 2'
FROM table1
```

Comment: just by looking at the query, it looks like this doesn't add 'Column 1' and 'Column 2'

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result of Column 1 + Column 2 for each row in table1 you can use this query:

```
SELECT [Column 1] + [Column 2]
FROM (
    SELECT  
        CASE
            WHEN x = 0 then 2
            WHEN x = 1 then 4
            ELSE 6
        END AS [Column 1]
        , CASE
            WHEN y = 0 THEN 3
            WHEN y = 1 THEN 6
            ELSE 9
        END AS [Column 2]
    FROM table1
) AS IntermediateResult
```

If you want the sum of all the values in Column 1 and all the values in Column 2 you can SUM Column 1 and Column 2.

```
SELECT SUM([Column 1] + [Column 2])
FROM (
    SELECT  
        CASE
            WHEN x = 0 then 2
            WHEN x = 1 then 4
            ELSE 6
        END AS [Column 1]
        , CASE
            WHEN y = 0 THEN 3
            WHEN y = 1 THEN 6
            ELSE 9
        END AS [Column 2]
    FROM table1
) AS IntermediateResult
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    SUM
    (
        CASE x
            WHEN 0 THEN 2
            WHEN 1 THEN 4
            ELSE 6
        END
    ) AS [Column 1],

    SUM
    (
        CASE y
            WHEN 0 THEN 3
            WHEN 1 THEN 6
            ELSE 9
        END
    ) AS [Column 2]
FROM
    table1
```

**SUM** two columns

```
SELECT 
    (
        CASE x
            WHEN 0 THEN 2
            WHEN 1 THEN 4
            ELSE 6
        END
    )
    +
    (
        CASE y
            WHEN 0 THEN 3
            WHEN 1 THEN 6
            ELSE 9
        END
    ) AS [Column 1]
FROM
    table1
```